# iOS - Push Notification with Sound only

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

When I get a push notification while my application is not active or closed, my device plays a notification sound. When my application is active or open, it does not play a sound on receiving a notification / message.

I want the notification sound to play even when the application is active / open. Please can someone help me achieve it?

```
  -(void)HandleNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{

    NSMutableDictionary * test = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
    NSMutableDictionary *alert_msg = [test objectForKey:@"alert"];
    NoteType = [alert_msg objectForKey:@"type"];
    Note_Student_id = [alert_msg objectForKey:@"sid"];

    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"School Link"
                        message:[alert_msg objectForKey:@"title"]
                                                    delegate:self
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

}
```

My notification looks like this:

```
  {
            aps =     {
                alert =         {
                    sid = 114;
                    title = fddsf;
                    type = 2;
                };
                sound = default;
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to play the sound in your HandleNotification method, just add inside.

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1004);
```

Comment: whats is default notification sound name

Comment: Thank you this work , but last thing I want sound just like notification sound , I try many codes from http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices but can't get this one

Comment: try with  `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kUserPreferredAlert)`

Comment: I think that my previous comment, doesn't work. You will have to choose one of the codes, or create your own sound, because iOS SDK does not bundle these sound files, you can find them on the device in the /System/Library/Audio/UISounds/ folder. However, I believe these files are copyrighted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSString* soundName = [[userInfo objectForKey: @"aps"] objectForKey:@"sound"];

if([soundName isEqual: @"default"])
    soundName = @"default_sound_name.mp3";

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:soundName ofType:@""];
SystemSoundID soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path], &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID);
```

you can not access notification default sound, so you should download it somewhere and add it to your project